# Missing Id from table shown in two columns

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to get the list of ID-numbers that is missing in a table.

```
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(id) from MYTABLE)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN MYTABLE on MYTABLE.id = Missing.missnum
WHERE MYTABLE.id is NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

List of missing ID-numbers:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

But I don't want the list to show all individual numbers - only a list with two columns like

My output should be:

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 |
| 7 | 9 |

---

Now I can see that my question was not clear enough.

I have a long list of thousands of rows of numbers;

2,3,4 .... 36
401,402,403 ... 807
1234,1235 ... 1240
etc.

I would like to present them as;

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 36 |
| 401 | 807 |
| 1234 | 1240 |

Comment: please tag your dbms

Answer (score 1):

Use the table join to itself

```
SELECT 
        t1.id AS [from],
        t2.id AS [to]
     FROM test t1
     JOIN
     test t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t2.id - t1.id = 2
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91b855e37ea428ce23745b925927835e)*